# Why DataAdapter is not Disposable

Tags: c#, .net, database-connection, dataadapter

I know there is probably an obvious reason but I can't find it..

I usually use the `using` statement during DB connection and data reading, but I can't use it on `DataAdapter` because it doesn't implement `IDisposable`.

Also: how can it behave after filling a dataset?

Does it close itself the connection?

Only close it or dispose it?

Do I have to dispose the internal connection by myself after the dataset filling? If so, why `IDataAdapter` doesn't have a related property/method?

Comment: IDataAdapter..other adapters should derive from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataAdapter dosn't implement IDisposable because it doesn't have any member variables that need to be handled outside of normal garbage collection.  In other words it doesn't need to implement IDisposable.

If your intrested you can see the source code to the Mono DataAdapter here : http://www.java2v.com/Open-Source/CSharp/2.6.4-mono-.net-core/System.Data/System/Data/Common/DataAdapter.cs.htm

In general if you going to close the connection after using it, go ahead in put the connection in a using scope, but its ok too to have a singleton and have multipal DataAdapters in multipal scopes using the same connection.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: The data adapter **is** disposable, see documentation msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/…. The mono DataAdapter might not be ... but this is not a mono question.

Comment: Its only disposable in 4.0 and up.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"www.java2v.com’s server IP address could not be found."*

Answer (score 3):

`DataAdapter` doesn't close the connection as you might want to keep using this connection to populate other `DataSets`.

The exception is when the connection wasn't in open state before `Fill` method was called (Thanx Richard): https://stackoverflow.com/a/2472886/2258

Comment: ..so why it is not disposable?

Comment: Careful with that answer. The Fill can close the connection; see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2472886/2258

Answer (score 3):

A `DataAdapter` instance does not hold references to unmanaged code. It simply acts as a "bridge" between the commands and the datasets.

> The DataAdapter serves as a bridge between a DataSet and a data source
>   for retrieving and saving data. The DataAdapter provides this bridge
>   by mapping Fill, which changes the data in the DataSet to match the
>   data in the data source, and Update, which changes the data in the
>   data source to match the data in the DataSet.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.aspx

Comment: mmm..but the Fill method doesn't require the connection, so I suppose that the adapter has a reference for it. This way the GC doesn't release the connection since the dataAdapter is alive, right?

Comment: The adapter itself doesn't have a reference to the connection. The commands attached to the adapter have references to the connection. See example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx